# Content Security Policy in Manifest Version 3 for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am having trouble migrating my chrome extension from MV2 to MV3. I read through the docs and still don't understand the Content Security Policy aspect of it.

I want to migrate this piece of the *manifest.json* file:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://cdn.firebase.com https://apis.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://kit.fontawesome.com/; object-src 'self'"
```

So far I have this:

```
"content_security_policy": {
   "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

But what about the links

```
https://www.google-analytics.com https://cdn.firebase.com https://apis.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://kit.fontawesome.com/
```

Comment: @Bravo No worries! I guess I need to continue researching while waiting for a response here

Comment: Manifest v3 [prohibits the loading external scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code) in the `script-src` directive - all external scripts must be included in the application itself.

Comment: Any solution found for V3 on CSP ?